# Using custom HTML elements vs HTML elements w/ IDs or classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, createelement

Out of curiosity, what, if any, impact will it have on a site or page if instead of using IDs or classes for elements, you simply create custom elements w/ JS and stylize them with CSS?

For example, if I create an element "container" and use it as `<container`> instead of `<div class="container">`, is there a performance difference or something?

I don't see this being used often and am wondering why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's like saying "What if I respect the syntax and grammar of English, but make up all the words?" While this thinking makes for [good poetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabberwocky), it doesn't lend itself well to technical fields ;)

HTML has a defined set of tags which are [valid](http://validator.w3.org/). If you use any tags which are made up, it will be invalid.

Now, that doesn't mean you can't get away with it; [on the World Wide Web forgiveness is the default](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/04/javascript-and-html-forgiveness-by-default.html) so if you used tags which you made up it wouldn't be the end of the world... but it would still be a bad idea because you'd have no guarantee how browsers handle those tags.

So the only real answer to "what impact will it have on a page if instead of using IDs or classes for elements, you simply create custom elements w/ JS and stylize them with CSS?" is *anything could happen*. **Since you'd be using non-standard HTML elements, you'd end up with non-standard results, which none of us should try and predict.**

If you really want to (and/or need to) use custom elements, look into XML. In XML you can "make up" your tags, but can still apply CSS and open the documents in a browser.

For example, save the following two files, and then open the XML file in a browser:

### index.xml

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="style.xml.css"?>
<example>
 <summary>
     This is an example of making up tags in XML, and applying a stylesheet so you can open the file in a browser.
 </summary>
 <main>
     <container>This is the stuff in the container</container>
 </main>
</example>
```

### style.xml.css

```
summary {
    display:none;
}
main container {
    border:2px solid blue;
    background:yellow;
    color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for not assuming I'm an idiot and just answering the theoretical question clearly! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

HTML is standardized, you can't simply invent new elements. Some browsers will render the text content of an element they don't recognize, but not all will, and your HTML will not be valid HTML in such a case.

Comment: Sure you can invent new elements, Dabbler. It's called createElement :P

Comment: Well, I've never had a problem with (for example) the "unknown" HTML5 elements rendering in IE6 (`<section>` or `<article>`), but your point is still correct. The main risk is that someday somebody might decide that `<container>` means, "blinking picture of a purple rabbit" or something.

Comment: My point is, you can't invent new elements and still have valid HTML.

Comment: @Pointy: Not just that. The browser could ignore the element entirely if it wanted to.

Comment: Yes, true; that would be another possible change in behavior, and probably more likely :-)

Comment: So other than non-standard HTML, there are no performance issues? I wonder what kind of impact this would have on SEO. I'm pretty aware it's not standard. That was kind of the point of the question.

Comment: No, I wouldn't worry about performance issues at all in this case.

Comment: The browser could not "ignore the element entirely", there are backwards compatibility rules to define the behaviour in these cases. See, for example, the HTML5 audio element, which specifies that any content inside the element can be used as fallback for browsers which don't recognise "audio" - this only works because rules exist for how to deal with unknown elements in existing browsers.

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/appendix/notes.html#notes-invalid-docs. The spec *recommends* the browser try to render the contents, but that section is not mandatory.

Comment: OK, thanks for that pointer. In practice, all browsers do follow that.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is a defined language, the elements and tags have certain meaning within the format. You cannot invent a new element not only because browsers may render those elements inconsistently, but also because the meaning and structure of the document becomes invalid.

You are best using the element that has the correct meaning for the content you wish to deliver. If you require a generic container for styling, the correct element is a div. There are similar elements that also provide some semantic meaning. I would recommend checking out a HTML tag index and HTML5 doctor for assistance in picking the correct element.

It sounds as though `<div class="container">...</div>` is the closest to what you need from your brief description.

Comment: Stuie, the question is just theoretical. Other than standards, are there any performance issues? Is this not good for SEO? Etc. I understand that this isn't standard HTML, I'm not just learning how to write HTML.

Comment: If you wanted to, sure you could write a load of <oldbull>tags</oldbull>... Performance wise you are unlikely to find significant problems as most browsers will render unknown elements as inline elements I believe. IE will ignore rendering them in most cases. SEO wise, you do so at your own risk, I would imagine most search engines have had enough experience of indexing <gibberish>sites</gibberish> over the years... Whether they have adopted a strategy of penalizing rubbish markup I don't know. The reason I respond as above is that there are plenty of adequate elements for what you need to do.

Comment: In addition, if you need IE to apply styles to your invented elements you need to include a script document.createElement("myinventedelement"); in your markup... For some bizarre reason IE then decides it should apply style rules to those elements... Just... Don't do it...

Answer (score 1):

If custom elements make your HTML easier to read and manage, go ahead and use them.

Since this question has been asked, custom elements have since been added to the [WHATWG HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-autonomous-example), along with an associated JavaScript API. Some web component frameworks are already implementing some of these specifications. It's no longer taboo like it was back in 2011. (I remember having some unpleasant issues dealing with the DOM in Internet Explorer when trying to use newly-announced HTML5 elements.)

As of writing this (November 2018), custom elements have been implemented into several major browsers. However, the MDN lists Microsoft Edge as having not yet implemented custom elements, although a [blog post from 2015](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/14/bringing-componentization-to-the-web-an-overview-of-web-components/) says that the Edge team is "excited to continue to support and contribute to this journey."